# Approximate Column Matched

Tags: excel

I have two column in excel. Col1 and Col2

i want to know that if 80% column strings are matched then it display matched and if less then 80% then it should display mismatched,
It is not necessary that both the string are in same case. like 'Student' and 'STUDENT' considered as matched.

[image]

Comment: What is a match? 80% of the words? Or 80% of the characters? And if the first, you have only matches 75% of the words in col1.

Comment: 80% OF STRING MATCH..  OR EVEN 70% That can be change ...

Comment: Like fuzzy lookup, is there any formula that identified the matching among records..?

Comment: Do the substrings need to be in the same order?  Or can the words in column 2 be randomly ordered?

Comment: word or string can be in any order..